# How do I stretch a container in flutter so that it occupies the remaining screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to maximize the screen as there is an unused white gap at the bottom (below the green bar which is the countdown/timer for the qn) :

[image]

Code:

```dart
    final quizBottomContentText = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left:30.0, right:30.0, top: 30.0, bottom: 30),
      child: Text(
        questions[questionNum].title,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
      )
    );

    final quizOptions = Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right:40.0, bottom: 40.0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
                  children: questions[questionNum].options.map<Widget>(
                    (option) =>  SimpleRoundButton(
                        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(58, 66, 86, 1.0),
                        buttonText: Text(option, 
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white
                            ),
                        ),
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                        onPressed: (){},
                    ),
              ).toList(),
        )
      )
    );

    final countdown = CountdownWidget(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          duration: 20,
          triviaState: triviaState,
        );

    final quizBottomContent = Container(
     width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[quizBottomContentText, quizOptions, countdown], // need countdown 
      ),
    );
```

I've been trying the following but I cant seem to get what I want:

```dart
 // Column for quizBottomContent
 mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your bottom widget in `Column` inside `Expanded` (I think, this is what you want)